# Show and hide an item at a specific time

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I show this?

```
<a id="pupupads" href="https://google.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

Once per user every 5 minutes

It only appears to the same user once every 5 minutes

Comment: All I see is an empty anchor tag. What are you going to show to your audience?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you've done so far? What have you done that causes it to appear to the same user once every 5 minutes?

Comment: A link to go to a page, but it appears once every 5 minutes. If the same user enters the page, it does not appear to him until after 5 minutes

Answer (score 2):

I think you can easily do that with some JS.

try:

```
<a id="pupupads" href="/" target="_blank"></a>
<script>
    const link = document.querySelector('#pupupads');
    setInterval(()=> {
        link.style.display = link.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
    },1000*60*5)

</script>
```

The above code will simply make hidden or show the link once every 5 minutes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Display does not have a "hidden" value, you probably meant to use "none". Using a "hidden" class might be better, it would support more display types like grid and flex.

Comment: It doesn't work, it appears again to the same user

I want if the same user enters the page, it does not appear to him until after 5 minutes, then the ip must be registered or logged in the browser cache so that it does not appear until every 5 minutes for the same user

Comment: @GauravPunjabi you're totally right!

Comment: @ibrahimramy try using `localStorage`  to keep info about the current user and add some code in the `setInterval` to check whatever it is that you want to check and decide whether to hide the link or not

Comment: A simpler approach would be showing or hiding the element based on the clock time.